# Excel VBA: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support

Tags: vba, excel

**Please help debug: `Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method`**
For this code to copy value from workbook to another, i do that yesterday but i forgot saving that, i try today but it doesn't work

---

```
Sub Listcustomer()

    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim x As Workbook

    Set y = ActiveWorkbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\myNetworkSharePath\myFileName.xlsx")

    For i = 1 To x.Sheets.Count
        y.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i + 3).Value = x.Sheet(i).Range("b3").Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 4):

Typo. Change Sheet to Sheets

```
 y.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i + 3).Value = x.Sheets(i).Range("b3").Value
```

Comment: @M.AlAbsi Accept the answer so that visitors can understand this answer solves your problem. Tick this as green to accept.